# SAPUI5 Input currency not validating decimal point for JPY

Tags: sapui5, currency

I've setup an input field as a currency type, and also included error handling by adding the following to the manifest.json

"`handleValidation": true,`

```
<Input value="{parts: ['pendingData>/data/netPrice', 'pendingData>/data/currency'], type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false} }" id="pendingNetPriceInput"  change="onInputChange"/>
```

This works fine for GBP for example, correctly showing an error when inputting an invalid character.

However, when the currency is JPY, this should not allow entry of a decimal point, which is an invalid character for this currency, but SAPUI5 is not showing the error in this case.

I've checked the TCURX table in ECC and JPY is set to 0 decimal places.

Why is the decimal point not erroring for JPY?

Comment: What is the target UI5 version?

Comment: UI5 version is 1.77.2